# Angular JS controller is returned by AJAX?

Tags: angularjs

I have HTML file at server with `ng-controller`:

```
<div id="ng-app" ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller="AppController" nv-file-drop="" uploader="uploader">
</div>
```

This file is token by request AJAX and is returned at page. But this controller is not active. How to fix it?

Example:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '...',
        success: function(response) {
            $('body').html(response.html); // where html is template from server with controller
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you create a full example? Using some online js\html editors is preferred

Comment: Updated question. Angular JS did not load this template during building DOM page, seem this problem

Comment: When Your ajax response end as success do You have any other ng-app initialized above that one from response?

Comment: When AJAX response, I have one initialized `ng-app` also AJAX returns yet `ng-app="app"` with controller that not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to bootstrap it.

```
  $.ajax({
        url: 'response.html',
        success: function(response) {
            $('body').html(response); // where html is template from server with controller
            angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("ng-app"), ['app']);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I get errro: `Uncaught Error: [ng:btstrpd]`

Comment: You are probably bootstrapping it twice: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/btstrpd